# Web server on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu, port 80

Tags: web-server, java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How to set up a web server on a EC2 Ubuntu on port 80?

There already seems to be a daemon listening on port 80 by default? What is that daemon and is it safe to kill it?

```
#lsof -i
java       1290   root   41u  IPv6   3856       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the image you are using came with a web server by default. I saw a similar issue with the Fedora 8 LAMP image. I just killed the default daemon and install httpd from the yum repositories. Anyways I'd choose an image with no web server installed by default.
Which image are you using? Maybe the provider of the image has some documentation about the web server installed.

Comment: Futhermore, it looks like Tomcat or some other java based web server that is installed on the image he used.

Comment: @All: Yep, it appears so. My image came with a pre-installed java web server. I terminated it and went for a Fedora with LAMPP.